# Trying to get transpose table in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

The below is the query used to get the transpose of the table.

```
SELECT  month,
        CASE WHEN year = '2016-17' THEN sum(Amt) end,
        CASE WHEN year = '2017-18' THEN sum(Amt) end
FROM   
(   select year, month, type, sum(item_amt) as Amt 
    from `dummy` 
    where type = 'XYZ' AND party_code != 'Interunit' AND (item_acc_code='301010100001' OR item_acc_code='301010100002') AND (YEAR(inv_date)=YEAR(CURDATE()) OR YEAR(inv_date)=YEAR(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR))) 
    group by month,year
) T
group by month,year
```

Current Output

```
month || CASE WHEN year='2016-17' || CASE WHEN year='2017-18'
Apr   || 1487                     || NULL 
Apr   || NULL                     || 1847
May   || 1591                     || NULL
May   || NULL                     || 1234
```

Desired Output

```
month || 2016-17 || 2017-18
Apr   || 1487    || 1847 
May   || 1591    || 1234
```

We are facing 2 issues:- a) Alias cannot be given for the output columns b) Group by month values should be shown in one row, by not considering the NULL value.

Comment: a) Why not? b) See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I was attempting an answer, but then realized that your query and data are in such a mess that the odds of my guessing correctly were very low.  That being said, please update your question and show sample data along with your expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try the query below. I think you don't need to use sub-query**

```
SELECT
    MONTH,
    SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR = '2016-17' THEN item_amt ELSE 0 END) '2016-17', 
    SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR = '2017-18' THEN item_amt ELSE 0 END) '2017-18'
FROM dummy
WHERE TYPE = 'XYZ' AND
      party_code != 'Interunit' AND
      (item_acc_code='301010100001' OR item_acc_code='301010100002') AND
      (YEAR(inv_date)=YEAR(CURDATE()) OR YEAR(inv_date)=YEAR(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR))) 
GROUP BY MONTH
```

Comment: This might show months belonging to years other than what the OP wants in the result set.

Comment: Hi, I don't see the Year column on [Desired Output] table. Where is it?

Comment: Error : #1111 : Invalid use of group function

Comment: @Fresher I think this answer is close to what you want, but why can't you show us sample data?  This would make the query you want transparent.

Comment: @Fresher, please give us sample data. I will correct the sql either you can correct the syntax by yourself. I think you just need the idea is enough

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i have already updated the desired output required.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen we got the right values for 2016-17 but 2017-18 its coming 0 for both the months.                                                                                                                             Current Output :                                                                                                     month || 2016-17 || 2017-18
Apr   || 1487    || 0 
May   || 1591    || 0

Comment: Error : #1111 : Invalid use of group function –
=> Did you try again to run my sql? It's corrected!

Comment: @hiule got the desired output. Thanks !

Comment: @Fresher, I updated the query. Add IFNULL(item_amt, 0) into query

Answer (score 1):

As you are selecting appropriate year in case statement, you should remove year from external grouping. As for the aliases - use brackets around `case` statement

```
SELECT  month,
        (CASE WHEN year = '2016-17' THEN sum(Amt) end) as year1617,
        (CASE WHEN year = '2017-18' THEN sum(Amt) end) as year1718
FROM   
(   select year, month, type, sum(item_amt) as Amt 
    from `dummy` 
    where type = 'XYZ' AND party_code != 'Interunit' AND (item_acc_code='301010100001' OR item_acc_code='301010100002') AND (YEAR(inv_date)=YEAR(CURDATE()) OR YEAR(inv_date)=YEAR(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR))) 
    group by month,year
) T
group by month
```

Comment: I don't think the subquery is necessary at all.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thank You for the query it solved the Alias issue but the result is giving the entire sumation in year 2016-17 for both the months